# store month/day/year in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a mongoose schema with a created key. Currently I am using Date.now which is storing the date value as. 2022-01-12T22:23:49.621Z

Is it possible to store the data as a 01/22/2022 format in the database? Or do I always need to store in this above format and call date functions when I fetch from the db

Here is my model

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const fieldSchema = new Schema ({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    _user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now // Date.getMonth() + Date.getDay() + Date.getFullYear()
    },
    
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('field', fieldSchema);
```

Comment: It is ideal to store date data as the `date` object - and use date functions to work with month, year, etc. Also, date comparisons, arithmetic, sorting and searches will be simpler and efficient.

Comment: Storing date values as string is a design flaw! Here on SO you can find hundreds of questions where people have problems, because they did not use proper data type for date/time values, it applies also for many other database systems.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit So its best to just store date as 2022-01-12T22:23:49.621Z ? Then just run my date functions when I pull this data from backend?